# Wordpress visual page editor not working (Refused to frame 'blob', Content Security Policy directive)

Tags: wordpress

SOLUTION: "add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; frame-src 'self' https: blob:;" always;"

I have a simply web page based in wordpress in where I edit web pages with the wordpress visual editor.

It is weeks since my last edit, yesterday I begin to edit a new page with visual editor but .... I get a blocked content image. If I change from "visual editor" to "code editor" I can use it, but I can not use the visual editor.

In console I can see this message:

```
Refused to frame 'blob:https://xxxxxxxxxx/a2b69832-2d99-45dc-b760-766c6f933c04' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src *". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback. Note that '*' matches only URLs with network schemes ('http', 'https', 'ws', 'wss'), or URLs whose scheme matches `self`'s scheme. The scheme 'blob:' must be added explicitly
```

I have tried by deactivating all my plugins (only a few and not changes since months) but no luck. I have tried also but there isn't any update for wordpress

The server is a Google Cloud Free Tier.

Any key to investigate? Thanks a lot.

Just in case, my nginx.conf:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name xxxxxxxxxx;

        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
                allow all;
                root /var/www/html;
        }

        location / {
                rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
        }
        client_max_body_size 2M;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name xxxxxxxxxx;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        root /var/www/html;

        server_tokens off;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxxxxxxxx/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxxxxxxxx/privkey.pem;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
        add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
        add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
        # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
        # enable strict transport security only if you understand the implications

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
        
        location = /favicon.ico { 
                log_not_found off; access_log off; 
        }
        location = /robots.txt { 
                log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; 
        }
        location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }
        client_max_body_size 2M;
}
```

Comment: I have just tried also to activate the default theme of wordpress. No luck, same error trying to use visual editor. Web page shows correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you deploying your site?

If you are using nginx, you need to add the following to the policy: `frame-src 'self' https: blob:;`

What worked for me, when I had a similar issue:
`add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';" always`

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, I am using docker, and yes with nginx. For me it is strange that the errors has just appears without any update in any container. Please, could you update your answer with: 
1. where to update the policy if I am using a container?
2. where do I need to add the second line that you have proposed (also if I am using a container) ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where is your nginx.conf file?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. I have nginx.conf file located. But I am not sure where to add the first line and the second line you told me.
I have added code to my first post. Thanks a lot

Comment: add it instead of the `add_header Content-Security-Policy` in the second `server` section

Comment: Thanks, your help guides me to this other web page with the solution that works for me: "add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' https: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; frame-src 'self' https: blob:;" always;"
https://www.reddit.com/r/Wordpress/comments/163vvis/comment/jy5n6tt/
THANKS A LOT